# Using RXAndroid: Load Large JSON file from the Assets folder and pars it to a list view with pagination

Tags: android, json, java-stream, rx-java, rx-android

As mentioned in the question title, i need the best practice to load large **JSON** file from **assets** folder and parse it to be rendered in list view with considering the **pagination** for the list.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single **JSON** file and there is no way to divide it to a separate small ones then the best way I can think of is:

1. Show placeholder or loading while you are fetching the data(fetch data on background thread obviously)
2. Store it locally (I suggest using Room for this purpose, compatible with Rx and Paging Library)
3. Using [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) pass data from local DB to your list (use `recyclerView` instead of simple `listView`)
4. You can add [Diff Utils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil) so your in-list item management will be "smoother"

Obviously the best practice will be to not download a single large **JSON** file but to fetch data when user is about to reach bottom of the list or show "in-list loading" that is not blocking the user. This way he will not be blocked for a large amount of time.